# Is it possible to reference PHP embedded in an HTML document?

Tags: php, html

I've begun experimenting with PHP for a project (contact form for a website.) I assume the form's action would be an `action='example.php'` kind of deal. Using the Netbeans 8 IDE, I'm not able to create a PHP file in an HTML project, so I would need the PHP to be embedded into the HTML file itself. This leads me to my one major question: will I be able to reference my PHP in HTML if it's embedded the HTML document?

Any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: You cannot access PHP in HTML on the client side, as the server runs the PHP to produce the final PHP-free HTML. Also, it's actually a PHP file with embedded HTML, as it's the PHP interpreter that converts the hybrid file to browser-ready HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No, it's not possible.

**TLDR;** PHP is a Server-Side Programming Language, in order to compile it you must have a server to do so, that's why we use something like `xampp` on Windows or `mamp` to run a server to compile our PHP on the machine...

On the other side, HTML is compiled by the browser itself, not a server.

So, it's not really possible to embed your `example.php` inside your `example.html` in any way, the problem isn't related to the embedding process itself, it's about the know-how to compile that PHP Script

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a html project, just create a PHP project. Then, instead of creating .html files create .php files.

In a .php file, you can write any html code and, wherever you want to call PHP code, you must insert it between tags like so:

```
<?php … ?>
```

This implies, of course, a PHP server is active. Refer to the Netbeans documentation to declare a connection properly.

PHP code can be called *anywhere* from within a .php file as long as it is contained between the tags as indicated hereabove.

Practically, before sending back the .php page contents to the user agent, the PHP server will process the PHP code and insert the result into the relevant DOM element as specified in the HTML part.